# Why is JS Join adding the delimiter before the first value?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple image tags that a user can click on to "select" them. There is a hidden input tag that will be a CSV of the image IDs and it will serve as the list of selected IDs. When an image is clicked on and it was not previously selected, I want to add that image's ID to the hidden input. If the image was previously selected, it's ID should be removed from the hidden input.

I have the following HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buffet-315691_1280.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="464" class="selected-service">
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/computer-repair-Copy.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="95" class="selected-service">
<input type="hidden" name="selected_services">
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('img[data-service-id]').on('click', function() {
      $selected = $('input[name="selected_services"]').val().split(',');
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected-service')) {
        var removeItem = $(this).attr('data-service-id');
        $selected = $.grep($selected, function(value) {
          return value != removeItem;
        });

        $(this).removeClass('selected-service');
      } else {
        console.log($selected);
        $(this).addClass('selected-service');
        $selected.push($(this).attr('data-service-id'))
      }
      $('input[name="selected_services"]').val($selected.join(','))
    })
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remove Selected Services</button>
```

When the page loads and the user clicks on the first IMG tag before any of the others, a comma is inserted at the beginning of the hidden input's value. So if the first img tag is clicked and then the second img tag is clicked, the hidden inputs value is `",464,95"` when it should actually be `"464,95"` What am I doing wrong?

When logging $selected in console after clicking the first img tag once, there is only one item in the array(as it should be).

Comment: Possibly the `$selected` has whitespace at index `[0]`

Comment: `console.log($selected)` will give you some idea of  what is going on, as @Arvind has pointed out - most probably you have an empty position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the array `$selected` by splittng the `input`'s value, it will create 1 item of `""`, so to avoid that, check its length first, and if not greater than 1, just initiate it as an empty array `[]`.

```
  var i_val = $('input[name="selected_services"]').val();
  $selected = (i_val.length > 1) ? i_val.split(',') : [];
```

Stack snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buffet-315691_1280.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="464" class="selected-service">
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/computer-repair-Copy.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="95" class="selected-service">
<input type="hidden" name="selected_services">
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('img[data-service-id]').on('click', function() {
      var i_val = $('input[name="selected_services"]').val();
      $selected = (i_val.length > 1) ? i_val.split(',') : [];
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected-service')) {
        var removeItem = $(this).attr('data-service-id');
        $selected = $.grep($selected, function(value) {
          return value != removeItem;
        });

        $(this).removeClass('selected-service');
      } else {
        console.log($selected);
        $(this).addClass('selected-service');
        $selected.push($(this).attr('data-service-id'))
      }
      $('input[name="selected_services"]').val($selected.join(','))
    })
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remove Selected Services</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two main issues with the code:

1. There is an issue with the `.split` where it would have empty string in the array `[""]` which would lead to unexpected behavior in your code.
2. There is an issue due to how the logic is structured where it would not work on the first time you click on the images. It only starts to work from the 2nd click.

Here is the working version ... please note that I purposely made the hidden field visible so you can actually see the values during the demo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buffet-315691_1280.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="464" class="selected-service">
<img src="http://jadezebra.test/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/computer-repair-Copy.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-service-id="95" class="selected-service">
<input  name="selected_services">
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('img[data-service-id]').on('click', function() {

      $value = $('input[name="selected_services"]').val()
      $selected = !!$value.length ? $value.split(',') : [];
      var currentItem = $(this).attr('data-service-id'); 

      if($selected.indexOf(currentItem) < 0) {
 $selected.push(currentItem);
      } else {
 $selected = $.grep($selected, function(value) {
   return value != currentItem;
 });
      }
   
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected-service')) {    
        $(this).removeClass('selected-service');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected-service');
      }
      $('input[name="selected_services"]').val($selected.join(','))
    })
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remove Selected Services</button>
```